# Is there option to run some .exe when starting MSTest tests?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mstest

I'm writing tests using `MSTest`. I need to run executable from another project (in solution) before tests starts.

Is there other option beside invoking `exe` directly under `[ClassInitialize]`? In this case I'm loosing debugging capabilities.

Something like `Multiple startup projects` in solution properties.

Answer (score 0):

If it is in the same solution, can't you add a reference to it in your test project and call it directly from `[ClassInitialize]`. This shouldn't cause you to lose debugging capabilities. Do you not have access to the source code of the executable?